# Prove that $a b \leq \frac{a^{3}}{3}+\frac{b^{3 / 2}}{3 / 2}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, young-inequality

for any $a,b\in R^+$, how to prove that $$a b \leq \frac{a^{3}}{3}+\frac{b^{3 / 2}}{3 / 2}$$
my try: if I can prove that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\leq \frac{a^{3}}{3}+\frac{b^{3 / 2}}{3 / 2}$then this inequality can be proved but it seems that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}> \frac{a^{3}}{3}+\frac{b^{3 / 2}}{3 / 2}$  I had no clue then.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Hint: RHS $= \frac13( a^3 + b^{3/2} + b^{3/2})$.

Comment: Ohh, thanks very much

Comment: many thanks!...

Comment: Read up on weighted AM-GM inequality $\frac13a^3+\frac23b^{3/2} \geqslant ab$ is a direct application.

Comment: this is a verbatim special case of Young's inequality for products

Answer (score 2):

Write $ab = \sqrt[3]{a^3b^3} = \sqrt[3]{a^3b^{\frac 32} b ^ {\frac 32}}$. Apply AM-GM, recombine the $b^{\frac 32}$ terms.